# How to compare Individual data to aggregate group by in Google Query (SQL)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a table like this, with the current table in blue, and the desired results highlighted in yellow:

[image: Picture of Example Table]

And my goal is to set up a query in Google Sheets using their built-in `=QUERY()` function (note: based on the Google's own Query language, which is very similar to SQL) that can essentially do this entire table, without adding extra formulas. I know how to find the monthly averages separately, in a style like

```
SELECT month(DateRun), average(metric) GROUP BY month(DateRun)
```

But how could you have it so it's like

```
SELECT AdID, DateRun, Metric, average(Metric for Associated Month), IndividualMetric - AverageForMonth
```

I have tried to find it on my own, but have not been able to find a resource that I'm able to transform for my own usage.

I learned sub-queries a while back, and have a feeling that maybe the answer to this but I am very lost.

Please let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Comment: You can assist your query with vlookup, and you put your formula ini D2

Comment: Which columns or sheet actually you have for your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(MONTH(B2:B), 
 QUERY(B2:C, "select month(B)+1,avg(C) group by month(B)"), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

and:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="",,C2:C-D2:D))
```

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

[image: 0]

Comment: This is helpful, but the formula needs to be combined all into the top-left cell, so the two formulas on the right side cant work

Comment: not sure what do you mean by that. can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output?

Comment: Like there should be no formulas in D2, or E2. The query that runs in A2, should have the results of D/E but with only the query running in A2

Comment: what is your formula in A2? post it

Comment: currently just =QUERY("DataRange", "SELECT AdID, DateRun, Metric" This is a simplified version, as it has other WHERE criteria involved. If you'd like I can post the full one, but it may complicate things

Comment: sure, post the full one

Comment: `=QUERY(IF($D$2="Division1",'Division1'!$B$7:$N,'Division2'!$B$7:$N), 
"
select B,C,D,E,F,G,N  // aka (AdID, AdArtist,DateRun, Metric1,Metric2)

WHERE 
  Metric1 is NOT NULL 
  AND Metric1>=" & [Metric1 Minimum Input]
  & IF($D$2="Division1", "AND ("I IS NOT NULL OR L IS NOT NULL OR K IS NOT NULL OR J IS NOT NULL)","")
  & "AND B contains '" & [AdID Input] & "'
     AND C contains '" & [AdArtistInput] & "'

ORDER BY " & [ColumnInput] & " " & [DescOrAscInput] 
& IF([LimitInput]="","", " LIMIT " & [LimitInput] )
,0)`

Comment: Note: This Formula is actually in Cell B6

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet? - would be rly helpfull

Comment: I can't share the raw data (it's confidential) but I could try to throw together a mockup representation of the Data

Comment: It look like your data are from other sheets. I think this must be informed here clearly, so some one here can answer more near to your question

Comment: If your query in A2, how Will your D2 ia a string of devision name, and you hope the result Will be put on range A2:En?

Comment: The answer of @player0  (last update) more close to your question

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for a window average:

```
select 
    AdID, 
    DateRun, 
    Metric, 
    avg(Metric) over(
        partition by Metric, date_trunc(DateRun, month)
    ) month_avg_metric,
    Metric - avg(Metric) over(
        partition by Metric, date_trunc(DateRun, month)
    ) diff_with_month_avg_metric
from mytable
```

The last but one column in the resultset gives you the average of the metric for the on-going month, and the last column computes the difference between the current metric and its monthly average.

Comment: This is very helpful, but Google Query doesn't have the over() or "partition by" function/method. It's scope of available functions/methods is listed here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#aggregation_functions